/usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
I am trying to build package xgstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt with conf/distro/include/security_flags.inc included in my layer, and the error occurs.
here is the error msg:
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/Scrt1.o /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/crti.o /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/crtbeginS.o  .libs/libgstdecklink_la-gstdecklink.o .libs/libgstdecklink_la-gstdecklinkaudiosink.o .libs/libgstdecklink_la-gstdecklinkvideosink.o .libs/libgstdecklink_la-gstdecklinkaudiosrc.o .libs/libgstdecklink_la-gstdecklinkvideosrc.o linux/.libs/libgstdecklink_la-DeckLinkAPIDispatch.o   /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.so -L/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so -lz /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/liborc-0.4.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so -lrt /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libffi.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libpcre.so -lpthread -ldl -L/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0 -L/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/lib -L/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0 /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libstdc++.so -lm /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libssp_nonshared.a -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/crtendS.o /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/crtn.o  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z -Wl,relro -Wl,-z -Wl,now   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgstdecklink.so -Wl,-retain-symbols-file -Wl,.libs/libgstdecklink.exp -o .libs/libgstdecklink.so
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt/1.12.2-r0/build/sys/vcd'
| /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
| /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: .libs/libgstdecklink.so: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' isn't defined
| /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: final link failed: Bad value
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| Makefile:916: recipe for target 'libgstdecklink.la' failed
| make[3]: *** [libgstdecklink.la] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt/1.12.2-r0/build/sys/decklink'
| Makefile:1102: recipe for target 'decklink' failed
| make[2]: *** [decklink] Error 2
| make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-nm  .libs/libgstdvb_la-gstdvb.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-gstdvbsrc.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-dvbbasebin.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-cam.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camdevice.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camswclient.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camutils.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camtransport.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camsession.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camapplication.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camresourcemanager.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camapplicationinfo.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camconditionalaccess.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-parsechannels.o   | sed -n -e 's/^.*[    ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[     ][  ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' | sed 's/.* //' | sort | uniq > .libs/libgstdvb.exp
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: /bin/grep -E -e "^_*gst_plugin_.*" ".libs/libgstdvb.exp" > ".libs/libgstdvb.expT"
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: mv -f ".libs/libgstdvb.expT" ".libs/libgstdvb.exp"
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: echo "{ global:" > .libs/libgstdvb.ver
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link:  cat .libs/libgstdvb.exp | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\1;/" >> .libs/libgstdvb.ver
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link:  echo "local: *; };" >> .libs/libgstdvb.ver
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link:  arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/libgstdvb_la-gstdvb.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-gstdvbsrc.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-dvbbasebin.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-cam.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camdevice.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camswclient.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camutils.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camtransport.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camsession.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camapplication.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camresourcemanager.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camapplicationinfo.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-camconditionalaccess.o .libs/libgstdvb_la-parsechannels.o   ../../gst-libs/gst/mpegts/.libs/libgstmpegts-1.0.so -L/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib -lc /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libstdc++.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so -lm -lrt -ldl /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libffi.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libpcre.so -lpthread  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd -pthread -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z -Wl,relro -Wl,-z -Wl,now   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgstdvb.so -Wl,-version-script -Wl,.libs/libgstdvb.ver -o .libs/libgstdvb.so
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgstdvb.la" && ln -s "../libgstdvb.la" "libgstdvb.la" )
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt/1.12.2-r0/build/sys/dvb'
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt/1.12.2-r0/build/sys'
| Makefile:971: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
| make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt/1.12.2-r0/build'
| Makefile:902: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt/1.12.2-r0/temp/log.do_compile.25471)
ERROR: Task (/home/quinn/work/zj01_imx6_yocto/7100/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-qt5/qt5/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-qt_1.12.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5218 tasks of which 4817 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

I try several ways, but they don't work.

add extra ldflags in bb file

do_configure_prepend() {
    export EXTRA_LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -Wl,--undefined=__init_array_start -Wl,--undefined=__init_array_end"
}

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake LDFLAGS="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS"
}


remove ldflags added in security_flags.inc

do_configure_prepend() {
    echo "LDFLAGS with security_flags.inc: ${LDFLAGS}"
    # Remove specific problematic LDFLAGS
    LDFLAGS=$(echo "${LDFLAGS}" | sed -e 's/-Wl,--some-problematic-flag//g')
    echo "Modified LDFLAGS: ${LDFLAGS}"
}


compares the flags with security_flag.inc and without security_flag.inc, and try to remove the differences

-fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,relro

None of them works for me.

Solved by removing some flags in CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS:
SECURITY_LDFLAGS_pn-xf86-video-fbdev = ""
SECURITY_X_LDFLAGS = ""
SECURITY_LDFLAGS = ""
SECURITY_CFLAGS = ""

CFLAGS_append = " -fstack-protector-strong -fpie -pie"
CXXFLAGS_append = " -fstack-protector-strong "
LDFLAGS_append = " -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now"

